# How can I make my list breakup into sections?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code should break up the list into sectioned off groups that display the name of an expense and its cost. However it is instead showing everything in one list and inserting expenseName list items next to each other.  I'm not sure how I can make it breakup as I have changed the keys to insure that they are unique.

```
    //import statements
import "./App.css";
import {useState} from "react";
//declare default function
export default function App(){
  //expenseName variables
  const [expenseName, setExpenseName] = useState("");
  const [expenseNames, setExpenseNames] = useState([]);
//expenseCost variables
  const [expenseCost, setExpenseCost] = useState(0);
  const [expenseCosts, setExpenseCosts] = useState([]);

//handle form submission
  function handleFormSubmit(e){
    //prevent page from reloading
    e.preventDefault();
    //add an item to expenseNames
    setExpenseNames([...expenseNames,{
      id: expenseNames.length + 1 + "N",
      text: expenseName.trim()
    }])
    //add an item to expenseCost
    setExpenseCosts([...expenseCosts,{
      id: expenseCosts.length + 1 + "G",
      value: expenseCost
    }])
  }
  //handles input
  function handleInputChangeName(e){
    setExpenseName(e.target.value);

  }
  //handles input
  function handleInputChangeCost(e){
    setExpenseCost(e.target.value);
  }
  //returns app display
  return(
    /*div expenseList needs to display the list items in one group, 
    however is displaying them in seprate groups and putting names and costs together instead of with corrisponding item. */
    <div className="App">
      <div id="title">
        <h1>Expense tracker</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="createExpense">
        <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
          <input required="required" placeholder="Enter expense name..." type="text" name="expenseName" value={expenseName} onChange={handleInputChangeName}></input>
          <input required="required" placeholder="Enter expense cost..." type="number" name="expenseCost" value={expenseCost} onChange={handleInputChangeCost}></input>
          <button>Save</button>
        </form>
        
      </div>
      <div id="expenseList">

        <ul>
          
          {expenseNames.map((expenseName) =><li key={expenseName.id}>{expenseName.text}</li>)}
          {expenseCosts.map((expenseCost) => <li key={expenseCost.id}>{expenseCost.value}</li>)}
        </ul>


      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an "expense name" and an "expense cost" are part of the same thing, don't store them separately.  Track one array of your objects:

```
const [expenseName, setExpenseName] = useState("");
const [expenseCost, setExpenseCost] = useState(0);
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState([]);
```

Add each new object to that one array:

```
setExpenses([...expenses,{
  id: expenses.length + 1 + "N",
  name: expenseName.trim(),
  cost: expenseCost
}]);
```

Now your data is structured more meaningfully and you can loop over it more effectively.  How you group your items is up to you.  For example, if you want each one to be its own `<li>` element:

```
<ul>
  {expenses.map(e => <li key={e.id}>Name: {e.name} - Cost: {e.cost}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Or if you wanted to use something other than a bulleted list, such as a table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {
      expenses.map(e => (
        <tr key={e.id}>
          <td>{e.name}</td>
          <td>{e.cost}</td>
        </tr>
      ))
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Overall, the point is that you should semantically structure your data into meaningful objects instead of keeping all values in separate arrays.  That way you can just use the data in its natural structure rather than spend effort trying to keep multiple separate structures aligned in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display expense against the cost? you can achieve it through some styling changes in css or You should consider using table tags instead of ul. check out https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).